# array is not empty but still getting the error index 0 bounds

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I am using SQLite and I want to save the name, address, and phone text fields for them to show up in the next view controller for when the "show details" button is clicked in 1st VC.

I placed "save" and "show details" button in 1st VC, as well as "previous" and "next" button in 2nd VC. Whenever I click on "show details" I am getting this error message:

> index 0 beyond bounds for empty array.

However, I see that the array is not empty.  I want to store the student details in the array.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];



    NSString *homeDirectory = NSHomeDirectory();
    NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [homeDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
    self.dbFilePathInDocuments = [documentsDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"details.db"];
    self.studentDetails = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    NSString *selectQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select name,address,phone from contacts"];
    sqlite3_open([self.dbFilePathInDocuments UTF8String], &dataBase);
    sqlite3_prepare_v2(dataBase, [selectQuery UTF8String], -1,&selectStatement, NULL);
    while (sqlite3_step(selectStatement) == SQLITE_ROW)
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *studentDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        NSString *name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",sqlite3_column_text(selectStatement, 0)];
        NSString *address = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",sqlite3_column_text(selectStatement, 1)];
        NSString *phone = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",sqlite3_column_text(selectStatement, 2)];
        [studentDict setObject:name forKey:@"name"];
        [studentDict setObject:address forKey:@"address"];
        [studentDict setObject:phone forKey:@"phone"];
        [self.studentDetails addObject:studentDict];
        NSLog(@"student is:%@",self.studentDetails);
    }

    sqlite3_finalize(selectStatement);
    sqlite3_close(dataBase);

    self.nameLabel.text = [[self.studentDetails objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"name"];
    self.addressLabel.text = [[self.studentDetails objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"address"];
    self.phoneLabel.text = [[self.studentDetails objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"phone"];

    currentStudentIndex = 0;

}

- (IBAction)clickPrevious:(id)sender {
    if(currentStudentIndex <=0)
    {
        currentStudentIndex = 0;
    }else
    {
        currentStudentIndex = currentStudentIndex - 1;
    }


    self.nameLabel.text = [[self.studentDetails objectAtIndex:currentStudentIndex] valueForKey:@"name"];
    self.addressLabel.text = [[self.studentDetails objectAtIndex:currentStudentIndex] valueForKey:@"address"];
    self.phoneLabel.text = [[self.studentDetails objectAtIndex:currentStudentIndex] valueForKey:@"phone"];
}


- (IBAction)clickNext:(id)sender {

    if(currentStudentIndex >= [self.studentDetails count] - 1)
    {
        currentStudentIndex = [self.studentDetails count] - 1;
    }else
    {
        currentStudentIndex = currentStudentIndex + 1;
    }

    self.nameLabel.text = [[self.studentDetails objectAtIndex:currentStudentIndex] valueForKey:@"name"];
    self.addressLabel.text = [[self.studentDetails objectAtIndex:currentStudentIndex] valueForKey:@"address"];
    self.phoneLabel.text = [[self.studentDetails objectAtIndex:currentStudentIndex] valueForKey:@"phone"];
}
```

Comment: if it says the array's empty, then array's empty, and you're looking at something else that ISN'T empty.

Comment: Can you format the code

Comment: Show the complete stacktrace and the code it refers to.

Comment: What makes you so certain that the array isn't empty?  Have to tried setting a breakpoint and checking what's happening in the code while it's running?

Comment: use firstObject, it won't crash if array is nil; or use @try/@catch

Comment: @JasperPol That is not true.  The thing to do is not access an array index where index > count - 1.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it won't crash if you use firstObject @trojanfoe

Comment: @JasperPol Yes it will.

Comment: @trojanfoe please test it and come back to me to say sorry ;-)

Comment: @JasperPol So you are saying `firstObject` won't cause an exception where `objectAtIndex:0` will?

Comment: Exactly what I'm trying to say

Comment: Well if it does it does.  But you shouldn't be accessing elements that don't exist.

Comment: @JasperPol : where should i use that @try/@catch . ?

Comment: @JasperPol it isn't a good practice use a @try/@catch block for an index access on an array. However `firstObject` will return `nil` if the `NSArray` is empty, but not if it is also `nil`

Comment: @Krish where you are accessing the objectAtIndex from your array, put that in a '@try' block, it will not crash, but it will not fix your problem that the array is nil either

Comment: @JasperPol You should post an answer with your excellent coding advice.

Comment: @trojanfoe I don't have an answer to his problem why his array is empty, I do have a suggestion on how to not make it crash anymore. You just learned something, no need to be cranky about it

Comment: His array isn't `nil`, it's empty.

Comment: @LucaD Not exactly true, both nil and empty array's will return nil from firstObject

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you always accessing the array `self.studentDetails` even if it's empty.  This will cause an exception.

First limit setting of the labels to a single method and check the array access will succeed *before* attempting it:

```
- (void)updateLabels
{
    if (currentStudentIndex >= [self.studentDetails count])
        return;
    self.nameLabel.text = [[self.studentDetails objectAtIndex:currentStudentIndex] valueForKey:@"name"];
    self.addressLabel.text = [[self.studentDetails objectAtIndex:currentStudentIndex] valueForKey:@"address"];
    self.phoneLabel.text = [[self.studentDetails objectAtIndex:currentStudentIndex] valueForKey:@"phone"];
}
```

and use that method in the 3 places you currently set the labels.  For example:

```
- (IBAction)clickPrevious:(id)sender {
    currentStudentIndex--;
    [self updateLabels];
}

- (IBAction)clickNext:(id)sender {
    currentStudentIndex++;
    [self updateLabels];
}
```

In the `viewDidLoad` method use this code:

```
...
sqlite3_finalize(selectStatement);
sqlite3_close(dataBase);
currentStudentIndex = 0;
[self updateLabels];
```

After that you're gonna want to work on enabling/disabling buttons depending on whether there is a *next* or *previous* student to view to make using the app more intuitive.

Comment: how you are saying self.studentDetails array is empty ?

Comment: I did what you told me to do but still the same error

Comment: Do i need to change anything in the First VC ? "save" button ? if u want i will post the code ?

Comment: If you still have the same error then it's not in the code you've shown us. Take the principles of my answer to similar patterns elsewhere in your app.

Comment: i have 2 rows with name,address,phone in my table . Only this information is being populated when i click "show details". and when i continue click show details it is throwing this error even though i entered new information in those text fields ? this is the error

Comment: {
        address = "<UITextField: 0x8a91840; frame = (102 77; 151 30); text = 'tibet'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x8a97190>; layer = <CALayer: 0x8a919e0>>";
        name = "<UITextField: 0x8a98420; frame = (102 20; 151 30); text = 'krishna ravi'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x8a2d600>; layer = <CALayer: 0x8a98560>>";

Comment: Thanks trojanfoe you have cleared most of it .. but my question is..If i enter new information in those text fields and save it.. it should show right ? but it is not showing ?. it is throwing above error. but i am able to see whatever information which i have kept in table.

Comment: @Krish OK, if I've solved the issue, please upvote and accept the answer.  I am not providing extended developer support here.